# Django: stream an image file right into template using requests

Tags: django, python-3.x

Using requests I am fetching an image from a server. Instead of writing this file out and then using it to load into the template, I am trying to parse the contents onto the view (image data inline or another method).

Below is the partial output from r.contents:

```
b'/x89PNG/r/n/x1v/n/x0e/x20/x20/rIHDR/x00/x00/x22/xdb/x00/x00/x01/xad/x08/x06/x00/x00/x00/xc7/xe3/xb8/xe9/x10/x00/x00/x06bKGD/x00/xff/x00/xcf/x00/
```

Since its bytes, I tried to encode using base64 and then pass into the image data-url but haven't been able to render. Below is the partial output:

```
<img id="now" style="max-width: 100%; width: auto;" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,b&#39;iVBSDFSGcANSUhEUgAAAtsAAAGtCAYAAADH47jpAAAABmJLR0QA/wD/AP+gvSDFsfgsbfbvdsdsbdgndfnOy9eZwcV3nv/autt+mWRqPVY2ksCckWljXacAggexQvQK4NiXHEa1+JsbdfghgcEEOwlBwvHNIL8xvpFmwpIABl8I2HEYzJ4bY48AAzbyaEG2Lxfg463dR/Xpqaqufeuq6uf7+fSnu6vq1HOe012nTv3qqecABEEQBEfgdrcgbQBEEQBEEQBEEQBEEQBEEQfgdfgEEQBEEQAMA1
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Below is the sample view code in use, the code is meant to give an idea of this question:

```
def graph(request):
    unix_time = int(time())
    r = requests.get(f'http://192.168.1.10/graph.php?type=multi-port_bits_duo_separate&idb=393,204,132,31,36,214&to={unix_time}', auth=(USERNAME,PASS), stream=True)
    r.raise_for_status()
    # the write to file method, works but trying to stream contents into view 
    #with open(f'{unix_time}.png','wb') as fd:
    #    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=50000):
    #        fd.write(chunk)
    context = {'context': r.content}
    return render(request, 'live_graph.html', context)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `base64.b64encode()` (which I'm assuming you're using) is `bytes`. You need to convert that to a string before you hand it to the template for rendering.

For example:

```
decoded = base64.b64encode(r.content).decode('ascii')  # Convert to a string first
context = {'imagedata': decoded}
return render(request, 'live_graph.html', context)
```

And then in the template:

```
<img id="now" style="max-width: 100%; width: auto;" alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ imagedata }}"/>
```

The clue here was the initial `b&#39;` in your example base64 image data. That corresponds to `b'` which of course you don't actually want in the base64 encoded string itself.

Comment: you are correct my friend. I was using the same encoding method but failed to decode to ASCII - the key element that was missing. Truly appreciate your valuable input :)

Comment: with calling the decode method on the bytes, should we use ASCII or UTF-8? I am curious

Comment: My understanding is that [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) represents binary data using ascii characters, and so `ascii` should be supplied to `decode()` when converting the bytes to a string. That said, `decode('utf-8')` will work, but I guess may not produce valid base64 characters.