# Can any one suggest how to render a pdf document using base64 string in html

Tags: django, templates, pdf, base64

Can any one suggest how to render a pdf document. I am using the same method suggested by Will Keeling, so instead of image, I am using pdf

```
<object id="documentFileViewModalContext" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"  data="data:application/pdf;base64,{{ base64_string}}" type="application/pdf" class="internal">
    <embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,{{ base64_string}}" type="application/pdf" />
</object>
```

And in python code as below

```
pdf_file = branchDocumentFileObject.document.path
file_handle = open(pdf_file, "rb")
base64_string = base64.b64encode(file_handle.read()).decode('ascii')
context['base64_string'] = base64_string

html_content = render_to_string("adminToolsApp/manage/branch/document/documentView.html", context=context, request=request)
returnStatus['status'] = 'success'
returnStatus['response'] = html_content
return JsonResponse(returnStatus, safe=False)
```

I would appreciate your suggestion Thanks Benny

Comment: Who is Will Keeling? What is the source article? And why do you return a json response?

Comment: Post I was referring is  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54127335/django-stream-an-image-file-right-into-template-using-requests/72505443?noredirect=1#comment128082578_72505443

Comment: Changed the python code to return render(request, "adminToolsApp/manage/branch/document/documentView.html", context).   But still not rendering in browser. I am checking in Chrome